# Firebase functions.config() not working even with .runtimeconfig.json in the correct location

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-tools

"firebase-admin": "^9.8.0",
"firebase-functions": "^3.14.1"

I've been using firebase for almost a year now and all of a sudden my functions.config() is returning an empty object.

This is the error that I receive `It looks like you're trying to access functions.config().myservice but there is no value there`. Note that I have triple checked that there is no misspelling issue.

I know my `.runtimeconfig.json` is in the correct location (`/functions/.runtimeconfig.json`) with the existing object inside of it but it still isn't being called properly.

I've also ran `npm run build` to make sure it wasn't a TS not being compiled issue but apparently that's not the case.

One other thing I have done is created another functions directory on a different project, one using TS (it wouldn't function properly) and one with normal JavaScript and the latter was the only one that would run.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue, but only after upgrading to firebase-tools@10.2.0. Downgrading to firebase-tools@10.1.5 is a workaround for me. From v10.2.0 and going forward, they are recommending using environment variables in the dotenv format instead of using functions.config().

Comment: I ended just renaming my functions folder, creating a new one using firebase init and copying over the configuration files, deleting the new functions folder and renaming the other back to functions.

Comment: firebase-tools@10.2.1 contains a fix to prevent the emulator from crashing when parsing triggers if accessing functions config values.